# Deleted Windows and data doesn't save when restarting

Tags: grub2, partitioning, format

I am a newbie so I have no idea what to do :p

I deleted windows when installing Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS from a usb and I clicked on format Hard drive and install ubuntu (or something like that).
   And everytime I boot up my system it shows the grub menu and there are a few options: Try ubuntu without installing, Install ubuntu, OEM install (I think)

Anyways I choose try ubuntu without installing and all my data is gone everytime. Is there any way to fix it and make my data there evertime I boot.

Sorry if I didn't make sense I can provide screen shots if needed.

Comment: Did you remove the usb after the installation ?

Comment: Have you tried to run `sudo update-grub`?

Comment: @Videonauth Nope I did not remove the usb after installation

Comment: @Danibix I tried to run *sudo update-grub* but I got I got this * error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.*

Comment: So what about to remove the USB ? so your system can actually boot into your fresh install?

Comment: The way it's done : 1) Plugin USB 2) Install Ubuntu 3) After install is successful , shutdown 4) Remove USB 5) Boot the computer.

Comment: @serg Ill try it and I hope it works, wish me luck.

Comment: @UnfaithfulBanana good luck :) Don't worry about a thing  - it all comes with practice

Comment: @serg I know this might be a dumb question but I finished installing and theres a pop up saying I need to restart but since you said shutdown will I just press the off button on my laptop? :p

Comment: @UnfaithfulBanana Well , I said shutdown because then you have time to remove the USB stick. You can reboot, too , but then once you see you computer booting again , you need to yank the usb stick out so that your system doesn't boot to USB stick. We want it to boot to your hard drive

Comment: @serg I pulled out my usb and when my laptop booted it says no bootable device

Comment: @UnfaithfulBanana OK  . . . Try going into your BIOS settings  ( pressing F8 or F12 at boot screen, depending on your machine ) and then change boot order of the laptop . The goal is to make HDD as #1 device in the boot order

Comment: @serg I'm in my BIOS settings and my HDD is the first one on the priority order.  (1.HDD: WDC WD10JPVX-22JC3T0) 2.Cd rom ect. And it still can't boot without the usb

Comment: @videonauth when I remove my usb my laptop can't boot

Comment: @serg I moved my usb to number 1 on the boot priority and when I went into the grub menu I removed my usb and it asked me to boot from HDD.  Thanks for your help I'm so relieved :)

Comment: @UnfaithfulBanana Always welcome !  Feel free to ask more questions if you run into other issues.  Enjoy your Ubuntu !

Answer (score 0):

With some help I fixed it

Go to your bios and change your USB to Number 1 on boot priority

Then go into the grub menu and remove your usb.

Click try Ubuntu without installing

:)) I will ask you to use your HDD to boot